# How does memory copy operations depend on Endianess?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, kernel, endianness, x86-16

I just did an assembly language programming only  to find that my Code didn't work. I skimmed through the code and found the problem with my understanding of Endianess.

My System is `Little Endian` and my code is as follows:

```
lbDest:
            .byte 0x0000
            .byte 0x0000
            .word 0x0000
            .word 0x0000
```

The above is the destination where I am supposed to copy the values to and the below is the source to copy from,

```
lbSrc:

        .byte 0x00
        .byte 0x00
        .long 0x00000001
        .long 0x00
```

And my code to copy values from Source to Destination is as follows:

```
       movw $lbSrc, %si
       movw $lbDest, %di
lbTempLoop:

        addw $0x02, %si
        addw $0x02, %di
        movw (%si), %ax
        movw %ax, (%di)
        loop lbTempLoop
```

---

**Concept:**

The concept be like, copy the `.long` value from `lbSrc` and place it in two words `.word` and again while fetching the words I should be able to get the same value that is in `.long`.

### **Note:** The above code is to run on 16-bit environment and therefore `movl` like instructions would not be apt.

OS: Ubuntu

Assembler: GNU AS

Endianess: Little Endian

Thanks

Comment: at `lbDest` you have 1+1+2+2 = 6 bytes reserved. `lbSrc` is 1+1+4+4 = 10 bytes. The copy code is simple copy without any conversion, so first `long` will land into those two words, and there's no room for second `long` (6-10 = -4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two iterations of your loop will produce the following:

```
lbDest:
    .byte 0x0000
    .byte 0x0000
    .word 0x0000     This will recieve a value of 1 (low word of the long)
    .word 0x0000     This will recieve a value of 0 (high word of the long)
```

Further iterations will start overwriting memory in the destination that is not defined here!

```
    movw $0x02, %cx
    movw $lbSrc, %si
    movw $lbDest, %di
lbTempLoop:
    addw $0x02, %si
    addw $0x02, %di
    movw (%si), %ax
    movw %ax, (%di)
    loop lbTempLoop
```

Comment: So, How can the remedy be?

Comment: It means, again when I read the value from lbDest, will I get 0x00000001?

Comment: Yes. The 2 words together form a long with the same value.

Comment: Provided you add the setting up of `%cx`